# Pressing keys on my keyboard sometimes makes another key appear

Tags: keyboard, hardware

I have an HP laptop running Ubuntu, and I ran into a problem with my keyboard. When pressing Shift + some specific keys, my keyboard appears to pass *two* keys instead of one. Those keys are J, K, L, M, `?`, `.`, `/` and `+`. When I press Shift+J or Shift+?, I appear to receive `J?` instead of the key that I actually pressed. (The J and the ? key are below each other on my keyboard, but I actually just press one key.) The same happens with the pairs <kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>/<kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>M</kbd>/<kbd>+</kbd>. When I do not press the Shift key in combination with one of those, it works fine though.

Additionally, when I boot my laptop, I hear several beeps. They all pass very quickly so it's hard to keep track of them or count them. I think that it might be because of the keyboard issue, but I'm not 100% sure of that.

I tried removing all keyboard layouts except the one I need (the Belgian layout), rebooting the system, even re-installing the system, but the problem still persists.

Does anyone know what is going on with my keyboard? Is it a software or hardware issue? And in either case, what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like hardware to me. Do you have any dual-boot systems installed or can you boot any live OS from a CD/DVD/USB? If this issue is present there as well, we can conclude you need a new keyboard (or should at least try to clean it, maybe that would already help a lot).

Comment: @ByteCommander The live DVD that I still had didn't want to boot, so I plugged in another keyboard in my laptop. The problem doesn't happen there. So it's a hardware issue?

Comment: I would think so although I can't say that I'm 100% sure.